# I whant to run a code online that can be used by everyone with a link

Tags: python, pickle, replit

I created a code that uses the pickle library so it can save some data on some files.
I want this code to be accessible to multiple persons that could type commands into the code that modify these files. But to do that, I need to run my python online to make it public to everyone that has a link. I tried the site repl.it that seemed good for this utilization but the problem is that when others persons try to use the code, the modifications are not saved and i think they have to create an account for repl.it to save modifications...

Do you have better solutions to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Might be a good time to learn `git`.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to reexplain again exactly what you are looking for.
If you just want to share code, so that everybody can download it and run on his own computer, then you could host the code in github or gitlab or if you have more experience publish on pypi.org. but people need accounts to update / modify on github or gitlab.

Alternatively (without advanced version control) you could use services like Dropbox and Dropbox app. Again accounts are required to modify data.

Or (much more complicated) you setup a special server and you decide who can do what.

Comment: thanks for you're answer @gelonida .
actually i as looking for a way to put the code online and that it can modify some files that are stored on a cloud.

Comment: so you need a server, that should execute the code, right. It's not supposed to run on the user's machine.

Not sure you get such a solution for free, though doing some tricks with github / travis might bring you there, but you might violate their policy.

Comment: OK...
thanks for you're help anyway !